# Android how to action bar action(customize layout) for different tabs?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-actionbar-compat

I am using Actionbar support library. I customized the title and added one button in layout.

Now, I have 2 action tabs with extension of fragment. I want use same button for different functions in different tabs.

I am using Actionbar activity. Below is my code.

**Custom action bar layout**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/app_green" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/selectAll"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**My first fragment**

```
   public class TestPhotos extends Fragment {

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    selectAll();
        }

        private void selectAll() {

            CheckBox b = (CheckBox) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
            if (AutoBackupSettings.getInstance().isPhotoBackup()) {
                b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                transferLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                transferLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (stickyAdapter != null) {
                        if (stickyAdapter.getSelectedCount() == stickyAdapter.list
                                .size()) {
                            stickyAdapter.deselectAll();
                        } else {
                            stickyAdapter.selectAll();
                            ((PhotosActivity) getActivity())
                                    .setActionBarTitle(getResources().getString(
                                            R.string.all));
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }

    }
```

**My second fragment**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setHasOptionsMenu(true);
         selectAll();

    }

    private void selectAll() {

        CheckBox b = (CheckBox) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
        if (AutoBackupSettings.getInstance().isPhotoBackup()) {
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (listAdapter != null) {
                    if (listAdapter.getSelectedCount() == listAdapter.list
                            .size()) {
                        listAdapter.deselectAll();
                    } else {
                        listAdapter.selectAll();
                        ((PhotosActivity) getActivity())
                                .setActionBarTitle(getResources().getString(
                                        R.string.all));
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

It's working fine in first fragment but I swipe to the second fragment and click on checkbox, it is working for first fragment but not for second one.

Comment: Post your code so we can help you.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti ::: I added my code please help me.